# php custom array sort only for 4 first elements

Tags: php, arrays

I need to sort an array that first four elements will be defined manually and the rest alphabetically. How can I achieve this?

```
    $array = array('navigation' => array('label' => 'nav'), 
                   'sponsors' => array('label' => 'spo'),
                   'points' => array('label' => 'poi'),
                   'direction' => array('label' => 'dir'),
                   'time' => array('label' => 'tim'),
                   'statistics' => array('label' => 'sta'),
                   'height' => array('label' => 'hei'),
                   'opacity' => array('label' => 'opa'),
                   'saturation' => array('label' => 'sat'),
                   'size' => array('label' => 'size'),
                   'attribute' => array('label' => 'att')
                   );
```

First four elements should be **size, opacity, time, points** and the rest should be alphabetically.

**EDIT**

Comments requested to show my attempts. I tried sorting it with uasort function but it's not working at all. Also I have no idea why.

```
    $order = array('size', 'opacity', 'time', 'points');

    uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
        $pos_a = array_search($a, $order);
        $pos_b = array_search($b, $order);
        return $pos_a - $pos_b;
    });
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? (Extract the first 4 elements into another array sort both arrays and append the rest of the array to the array with the 4 elements)

Comment: You should show an attempt at the task, and we can help you with it. We don't do the work for you here.

Comment: And your attempt should use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Comment: @Arjan: ksort should suffice.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: After having seen your answer, you're correct. My mind was looking for a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the four items from your array (make a copy if needed) and sort it by key:

```
$temp = array();

foreach (array('size', 'opacity', 'time', 'points') as $key) {
    $temp[$key] = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
}

ksort($array);

$result = array_merge($temp, $array);
```